# Syntax error parsing the JSON file. Nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, syntax-error

everybody! I'm trying to build a Google Pagespeed client in nodejs.
I get a json file with syntax errors for any url. For example: url: http://www.bbc.com/ , error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aidkq.png)
json file:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RliLb.png)

I need only the property "ruleGroups". I tried to extract it so jsonpath.query(d, '$.ruleGroups') - 
did not work out.
Help please understand, sorry if the issue is dilettian.

```js
    let key = 'key';
    let url = 'http://www.bbc.com/';
    let strategy = 'desktop';

    https.get({
    host: 'www.googleapis.com',
    path:  '/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) +
    '&key='+key+'&strategy='+strategy
}, function (res) {
    console.log ("statusCode:", res.statusCode);
    console.log ("headers: ", res.headers);
    res.on ('data', function (d) {
        let json = JSON.parse(d);
        fs.appendFile('log.txt', json);
    });
}). on ('error', function (e) {
    console.error (e);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to accumulate all the data, then parse in the “end” event:

```
let rawData = '';
res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
res.on('end', () => {
  try {
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
    console.log(parsedData);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }
});
```

More information: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Comment: @Blackbonny That's awesome. If my answer was correct, please accept it. It helps you, me, and other readers when they find this question.